# How to automaticly check in which controller action is executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, nopcommerce

Imagine the situation. I have large complex asp mvc project which contain thousands od routes. When I am on the page and I press F5 in browser I want to check which action in controller is executed, because I need to debug this action. How can I do this? It exist option which show all mvc pipeline? I browse nop commerce and I don't know, how fast debug it because I don't know when I should insert breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like this to the `_Layout.cshtml`

```
    <script>
        console.log('Controller is @ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")') 
        console.log('Action is @ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")')
    </script>
```

This way you will see the controller and the action inside browser console. [Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rH3AVS)